# How to create a searchable drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very long list of values that I would like to be selected with a drop-down menu with the ability to search items by typing the value as text. For instance, something similar to the search box in `www.google.com`... How can I do that with `jQuery`, `JavaScript`, `HTML` and `bootstrap`? Is there a shortcut?

Is it enough to add a class to the following razor view code?

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyProperty, fmDataContext.MySelectList, "Select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This renders only a normal dropdown and not what I want.

Comment: you can use jquery autocomplete

Comment: @JDias - what do you think about solution with datalist HTML element..?

Comment: The problem with jquery autocomplete is that it is another in fact from another package: ```jQueryUI```... Is this possible with ```bootstrap```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solution for this kind of task is simple HTML code with *datalist* element:

```
<form>
  <label for="properties">Properties</label>
  <input name="properties" id="properties" list="properties-list">
</form>
<datalist id="properties-list">
  <option>Property 1</option>
  <option>Property 2</option>
  <option>Property 3</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: This solution is satisfactory. However, it only allows search by entering the first part of the string, ie, if I enter, let's say, "ty 3", it doesn't show any item to select… By other way, this requires validation on submission to not allow the user to type any string.

Comment: @JDias - in that case you should use one of existing JS library - for example https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js or https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your requirement, I have a sample DEMO for you using the `jQuery` plugin [MagicSearch](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Dynamic-Autocomplete-Multi-select-Plugin-With-jQuery-magicsearch.html). The two lists (`idList` and `nameList`) that I have created are the `id`and `name` for each element concatenated in a single comma separated string. Once you have this string, you can extract out the required information for your requirement. You can tailor the plugin UI according to your need. This plugin takes in a `JSON` object as shown below for its working and you can read more about the callback functions in the documentation.

Working DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/pomygbk8/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Search for keywords</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/magicsearch@1.0.4/examples/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/magicsearch@1.0.4/examples/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/magicsearch@1.0.4/src/sass/jquery.magicsearch.scss" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="theme2">
    <div id="container">
        <h2>Search for keywords</h2>
        <section>
            <input class="magicsearch" id="basic" placeholder="search keywords">
        </section>
        <br />
        <input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/magicsearch@1.0.4/src/js/jquery.magicsearch.js"></script>
<script>
var idList="";
var nameList = "";
$(function () {

var dataSource = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"test\"}, 
{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"example\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"image\"}, 
{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"election\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"IPL\"}, 
{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"Fashion\"},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Movies\"}, 
{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Pollution\"},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"Modi\"}, 
{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Rahul\"},{\"id\":11,\"name\":\"Cricket\"}, 
{\"id\":12,\"name\":\"Market\"},{\"id\":13,\"name\":\"TestKeyword\"}, 
{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"testkeyword1\"},{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"testkeyword2\"}, 
{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"testkeyword3\"}]";


    $('#basic').magicsearch({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        fields: ['name'],
        id: 'id',
        format: '%name%',
        hidden: true,
        multiple: true,
        focusShow: true,
        isClear: true,
        multiField: 'name',
        multiStyle: {
            space: 5,
            width: 200
        },
        success: function ($input, data) {
            idList = idList + data.id + ',';
            nameList = nameList + data.name + ',';
           // alert(data.id);
            return true;
        },
        afterDelete: function ($input, data) {
            idList = idList.replace(data.id + ',', "");
            nameList = nameList.replace(data.name + ',',"");
            //alert(data.id);
            return true;
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```